# Why is there an engine cover in my Saturn Vue 2004? Also it has a CTU engine

Tags: engine

Saturn Vue FWD four-door with electric windows, bearing 154,000 miles on the clock.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you mean by CTU? The cover is on there for decoration. It's an easy way to make the engine pretty without doing any real engineering.

Comment: It also makes it (slightly) harder for the great unwashed to start fiddling....

Answer (score 1):

Engine covers are there to hide the complex-looking components of the engine. These often don't look attractive when opening the bonnet. It also prevents dirt getting to the top of the engine, where you would commonly be checking brake fluid, engine oil, transmission oil (if your gearbox has a dipstick for this), washer fluid and coolant when doing regular maintenance. And, it also has an added bonus of dampening the sounds the engine makes.

It also serves the purpose of dissuading the inexperienced from attempting to fiddle with their car. Some would also argue that it's to increase time taken for mechanics to work on your car, causing you to get charged more for labour costs, but that's mere hearsay.

As for CTU, I assume that's the engine block/engine type code.